# Comma-separated text boxes in listbox

Tags: wpf, separator, listboxitem

given a list of business objects with a fixed number of properties (for example List of person, and person with properties FirstName, LastName, City, Department

I would like to show each person in a listboxitem, and was able to define a datatemplate that does the display.

Now the question: I do NOT want to display a gridlike structure, but would like to see only filled textboxes, and they should be separated by commas:

"Karl, Miller, Chicago, Legal" when all fields are filled, but
"Harry, Manning" when city and department is empty and
"Maria, IT" when lastname and city is not set.

Which is the way to choose for this task?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use Trigger.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{DynamicResource x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Department}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This solution does not have commas, but I need to know exactly what you want it to look like before I can really suggest that.

Alternatively, use `MultiBinding` with an `IMultiValueConverter`.

Comment: Hi, your solution is right for not showing empty textboxes. For the remaining visible textboxes, I would like to separate them by a comma, so that I get "Karl, Mayer, Legal" when City is empyt , and I get "Miller, Chicago" when Firstname and Department is empty

Comment: And I Need single TextBoxes for each property, as I want to be able to still edit them, so any solution using a summarized string would not be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Solved this like this:
In Xaml I have this Structure:

...

```
            <local:CaptionedTextBox Caption="{x:Static p:Resources.EMail}"
                                    Text="{Binding EMail.Value}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding EMail.Value,
                                                         Converter={StaticResource LengthToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <local:SeparatorBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LastFilledToVisibilityConverter}}" />

            <local:CaptionedTextBox Caption="{x:Static p:Resources.Mobile}"
                                    Text="{Binding Mobile.Value,
                                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Mobile.Value,
                                                         Converter={StaticResource LengthToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <local:SeparatorBox Tag="HIDE" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LastFilledToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

So, basically I have list of alternating Text and Separator elements.

The last element in the list is a Separator with TAG=HIDE.

In the Converter I only set TAG for not necessary separators to HIDE and finally set the visibility for all separators regarding the TAG.